# macOS Big Sur menu bar color on Parallels

Tags: menu-bar, big-sur, parallels-desktop

Having macOS Big Sur installed in Parallels, I'm trying hard to change menu bar color according to the wallpaper used. This is needed to debug an issue with some macOS application.

And, seeing clearly on screenshots over the internet, setting black background image must change menu bar color to the black as well, despite the Dark or Light mode is set.

However, in my case, it always depends on the Dark/Light mode (please see the attached screenshot).
Is there some other configuration option? Or does this just doesn't work on Parallels?

[image]

Comment: Unless this is something new to Big Sur (which I haven't yet used) then the menu bar doesn't actually change colour depending on wallpaper, it just 'hints' a pale blurred version of what is underneath, eg - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlQ9F.png If the desktop is solid black, then you probably won't be able to tell, as it will just be slightly darker grey.

Comment: Looks like things were changed: https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/changemenubarcolor-simple-utility-to-change-macos-big-sur-menu-bar-color-by-appending-a-colored-rectangle-to-a-wallpaper-image.306420/

However, I wasn't able to test it in a real environment since didn't update mac to the Big Sur, just have it in Parallels.

Comment: OK, then it could be because Parallels isn't using some of the graphics acceleration (Metal2) required - but it's not something i can test, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Looks like this is a reason: https://forum.parallels.com/threads/metal-and-metal-2-support.342879/